# Восстановление пиктограммы в трее при перезапуске проводника

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Имеется программа, тихо висящая в фоне, без окон, только со значком (временами несколькими, через `Shell_NotifyIcon` создаваемыми-убиваемыми) в трее.

Но при перезапуске проводника (ну, например, сбой какой) эти иконки не восстанавливаются.

Подскажите, как корректно организовать при перезапуске проводника перезапуск :) своих иконок в трее?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подпишитесь на событие `TaskbarCreated`. Оно вызывается каждый раз при создании связки «Меню «Пуск» — Панель быстрого запуска — Панель задач — Панель уведомлений»; из неё нас интересует только последний пункт.

1. Объявите где-нибудь глобальную переменную для хранения идентификатора оконного сообщения, соответствующего имени *«TaskbarCreated»*:

   ```
   static UINT _uTaskbarRestartMessage;
   ```
2. Где-нибудь при инициализации приложения необходимо выполнить собственно подписку:

   ```
   _uTaskbarRestartMessage = RegisterWindowMessage(TEXT("TaskbarCreated"));
   ```
3. При получении оконного сообщения с `uMsg`, равным значению `_uTaskbarRestartMessage`, необходимо пересоздать все необходимые значки своего приложения так, как мы делали это первый раз при запуске приложения:

   ```
   LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
       HWND   hwnd,
       UINT   uMsg,
       WPARAM wParam,
       LPARAM lParam
   )
   {
       switch(uMsg)
       {
           // ...

       default:
           if(uMsg == _uTaskbarRestartMessage)
           {
               // Создаём иконки в панели уведомлений
               return 0;
           }
           else
               return DefWndProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Старые при этом удалять никак не нужно? Никаких утечек не будет?

Comment: @Harry, нет, ничего удалять [не нужно](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144179.aspx): *... When your taskbar application receives this message, it should assume that any taskbar icons it added **have been removed** and add them again.*